# AFNetworking 2.0 can't POST to DJANGO (GET message received)

Tags: ios, objective-c, django, afnetworking-2

I am having the weirdest of the problems trying to communicate with a Django API from a iOS device and POST a NSDictionary and can't seem to make it work.
Curious thing is: the same code works like a charm talking to a Ruby API.

This is my ObjC method:

```
- (void)makePostToServerWithClass:(NSString *)stringClass object:(NSDictionary *)parametersDict success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure
```

{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager setRequestSerializer:[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer]];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];

__block NSError *errorMessage;

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [manager.requestSerializer requestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:[baseURLString stringByAppendingString:stringClass] parameters:parametersDict error:&errorMessage];
[request setTimeoutInterval:120];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [manager HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
    success(operation, responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", operation.responseString);
    NSLog(@"ERROR2: %@", errorMessage.description);
    NSLog(@"ERROR3: %@", error.description);

    if(operation.responseObject)
        errorMessage = [self creteErrorMessageForOperation:operation error:error];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
    failure(operation, errorMessage);
}];

[manager.operationQueue addOperation:operation];
```

}

In that code, the URLString would be:

```
@"http://linuxServerIP:8080/api/v1/create_user/"
```

and the parametersDict would be a NSDictionary containing:

(lldb) po parametersDict

> {
>       "raw_password" = 1234;
>       username = testuser; }

On the Linux server, the Django debug prints:

> **[28/Mar/2014 13:04:29] "GET /api/v1/create_user/ HTTP/1.1" 405 4**

And the error I'm getting on iOS is:

> ERROR3: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start
>   with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.)
>   UserInfo=0xb44e5b0 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with
>   array or object and option to allow fragments not set.,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0xb44e860 "Request failed: method not allowed
>   (405)"}

The most curious thing is: I'm sending a POST and the Linux server prints the error as a GET.

Do you guys have any idea what I'm doing wrong?
As I said before, it works well on a Ruby API.

Comment: I think that, if this code works in a server with ruby and not in a server with django, then the server implementation is bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone stumbles on this same problem at any time, the issue was caused because I was using a POD called RNCachingURLProtocol to cache retrieved images and HTML pages from UIWebViews.
This POD, for some reason, interfered with AFNetworking not allowing it to make POST requests.
Once I removed RNCachingURLProtocol, everything worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this function from AFNetworking: -

```
(AFHTTPRequestOperation *)POST:(NSString *)URLString
                      parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
       constructingBodyWithBlock:(void (^)(id <AFMultipartFormData> formData))block
                         success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success
                         failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work as well.
This is how the method ended up:

    [manager POST:@"http://192.168.2.4:8080/api/v1/create_user/" parameters:@{@"username":@"userTest", @"password":@"123"} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"SUCCESS");
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"FAILED: %@", error.description);
    }];